# Render table rows with Polymer's <core-list>

Tags: polymer, web-component

I was trying to use `<core-list>` to render rows for a table like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <core-list data="...">...</core-list>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, it's not that simple. `<tbody>` can't contain `<core-list>` element so it's simply ignored by the browser (or at least I assume that's the reason).
I thought this is the most obvious use case for `<core-list>` but the official documentation doesn't mention using it with tables at all which is very surprising for me.

Maybe I'm just blind but I wasn't able to google anything so I'm wondering if I really can't use `<core-list>` in this way or my approach isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way is really to use just `<div>`s and style them to look like a table because of the reasons described in the original question.

This applied to Polymer 0.5 but the issue will probably be the same with Polymer 1.0 as well.

Comment: It's basically a browser issue not a Polymer issue.
Some browsers still don't allow the `<template>` tag in tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining table manually you can use **grid layout** for your **core-list** by setting grid atributte to true.